# Laravel pagination not working with tailwindcss

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, backend, tailwind-css

This is my controller file's index function

```
 public function index()
        {
            $projects = Projects::All()->paginate( 5 );
            return view('projects.index')->with('projects', $projects);
        }
```

And, This is my blade file's pagination code

```
@foreach ($projects as $project)

{{ $project->links('pagination::tailwind') }}

@endforeach
```

But, Still, there's an error, that is saying

```
BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not exist.
```

Comment: $projects = Projects::paginate( 5 );

Comment: you need to call the ```paginate``` method from query. But ```all``` method will return a collection. So thats the reason you are getting the error  ``` $projects = Projects::query()->paginate( 5 ); ``` will fix the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo. This is not correct:

```
{{ $project->links('pagination::tailwind') }}
```

Error 1: You are missing a 's':

```
{{ $projects->links() }}
```

Error 2: You do not have to put your links in the loop but outside the loop. normaly after the loop.

```
@foreach($records as $record)
{{ $record->field }}
@endforeach
{{ $records->links() }}
```

Suggestion: I prefer to tell laravel which paginator I am using in this file:
App/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
{
    Paginator::useBootstrap(); //bootstrap in this case
}
```

For tailwind, there is no need to specify anything, since it is the default.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view

Comment: Your solutions for "Error 1" and "Error 2" seems to conflict with each other. But none of this will solve the error message mentioned in the question, which was solved in comments 2 hours ago.